# how to connect php 5.4.4 to MSSQL server 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

Q : How to php 5.4.4 (xampp 1.8.0) to MSSQL Server 2005?

Status : I download SQLSRV30.EXE from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). And installed .dll files into my php/ext folder. And I setup extension at php.ini. But can't connect to MSSQL server 2005.

Comment: Start from enabling error_reporting(E_ALL); and check if any errors are produced.

Comment: this is error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect(); This is my connection $link = mssql_connect ($server ,'sa', 'pwd');

Comment: is the `php_mssql` extension enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You need use FreeTDS library. Its simple. Reffer link: http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP
But library php_dblib.dll for php 5.4 I not found.

I compiled it. You may download it here: http://inethub.olvi.net.ua/ftp/pub/soft/programming/php/ms%20sql%20driver%20for%20%20php%205.4.10/ or here: ftp://inethub.olvi.net.ua/pub/soft/programming/php/ms%20sql%20driver%20for%20%20php%205.4.10/ Its compiled with VC9 with nts.

Here is mirror: TS - http://www.sendspace.com/file/vtger3 NTS - http://www.sendspace.com/file/nkg2j4

SQLSRV30.EXE - reffer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.90%29.aspx
May be you need install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client.